# Difference of two Poisson processes with same parameter

Tags: stochastic-processes

If I have two Poisson processes, $X$ and $Y$, each with rate $\lambda$, then what is the rate of $Z$ where $Z=X-Y$.

Is it $2 \lambda$? and would this differ if $X$ and $Y$ had different rates?

Thank you.

Comment: $Z$ is not a Poisson process. It does not have support over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Learner Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Z$ would no longer be a Poisson process, because a Poisson process only jumps up. $Z$ can now be a negative.

The jump rate of $Z$ will be $2\lambda$ with the $Q$ matrix with each row being

$[ ....0, \lambda, -2\lambda, \lambda, 0, ...]$

If the rates are different, then it is just

$[ ....0, \lambda, -(\lambda+\gamma), \gamma, 0, ...]$

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. If I had $Z=XY$, then what would be the jump rate in that case? I am trying to understand how the jump rate changes based on the components of Z. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kabamaro you mean Z=X+Y? it would be $2\lambda$. $Z=XY$ is not a Poisson process. It doen't event jump even in step size of 1

Comment: I assume in this case Z would be Poisson with rate $2\lambda$ and jump rate $2\lambda$. Is that correct?

Comment: "I assume in this case Z would be Poisson with rate 2λ and jump rate 2λ"

this doesn't make much sense Poisson with rate 2λ  means its jump rate is 2$\lambda$

Comment: yeah you have a point, sorry if I misuse the terminology.

Comment: @Kabamaro otherwise you are right